# Can't understand a specific example in Python

Tags: python, loops

I am playing around with Python and wondering why this works:

```
def fir(word):
    for x in word:
        print word[3]
        break
fir('alex')
```

And this doesn't:

```
def fir(word):
    for x in word:
        print x[3]
        break
fir('alex')
```

Comment: Can you explain what you expected to happen differently, and why you expected that?

Comment: What do you think the value of `x` is?

Comment: Try `print(x)` and you will promptly be enlightened.

Answer (score 2):

Word is a string, and x will be taking successively every character of the string.

If you word is 'kthxbye' then x will be 'k' on the first iteration, and then 't' and so on.

Printing word [3] is printing the 4rth letter of the word each time (indexes begins at 0).

x is a character. There is no sense in taking the 4rth member of 'k' for example.

Comment: To add, characters are not subscriptable so even x[0] would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because "word" is a character array and x is a character  . When you do word[3] its legal operation since youre trying to get your allowed address space , but when you do x[3] then youre trying to do index out of range operation.